# Trying to understand the function of reduce in python

Tags: python, reduce

I recently received an answer from the stackoverflow fellow on my previous question and I tried to inquire more in order to understand the function but somehow no response so I wish to ask it here.

I wanted to know what is the k and v that used in the lambda represent? I thought it was representing like this......

```
k = dictionary ?
v = string ? # Did I understand it correctly?

dictionary = {"test":"1", "card":"2"}
string = "There istest at the cardboards"

from functools import reduce
res = reduce(lambda k, v: k.replace(v, dictionary[v]), dictionary, string)
```

since we use lambda then it loop each of the element within both of these variables. But why k.replace? Isnt that a dictionary? Should It be v.replace? Somehow this method works. I wish someone could explain to me how this work and please more details if possible. Thank you!

Comment: Does `help(reduce)` help? Note the order of its parameters.

Comment: I try to read from there but I still could not understand when two parameters are taken by this reduce function. The note only have info for one parameter. I would like to understand the above method so that I could apply it myself in the future.

Comment: It very easy to use reduce in a confusing and obfuscated way. It's also often overkill for the task. It works ok for things like a sum operation but when you have to hold so much information in your head to understand whats happening, its not good. A simple loop would sadly be clearer but not as 'clever'.

Comment: thank you and I finally get how it works. The only thing I can digest is why k takes in the string and v takes in element of dictionary. I thought it is in sequence. k as dictionary and v as string. Somehow when I try other test, it works in a way I know here but not from my example. But still, this example work when I use dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` is equivalent to repeatedly calling a function.

The function in this case is a lambda, but a lambda is just an anonymous function:

```
def f(k, v):
    return k.replace(v, dictionary[v])
```

The definition of `reduce` itself is (almost—the `None` default here is not quite right, nor the `len` test):

```
def reduce(func, seq, initial=None):
    if initial is not None:
       ret = initial
       for i in seq:
           ret = func(ret, i)
       return ret
    # initial not supplied, so sequence must be non-empty
    if len(seq) == 0:
        raise TypeError("reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value")
    first = True
    for i in seq:
        if first:
            ret = i
            first = False
        else:
            ret = func(ret, i)
    return ret
```

So, ask yourself what *this* would do when called on your lambda function.  The:

```
for i in dictionary
```

loop will iterate over each key in the dictionary.  It will pass that key, along with the stored `ret` (or the `initial` argument for the first call), to your function.  So you'll get each key, plus the string value that's initially `"There istest at the cardboards"`, as your `v` (key from dictionary, called `i` in the expansion of `reduce`) and `k` (long string, called `ret` in the expansion of `reduce`) arguments.

**Note that `k` is the full text string, not the string used as the key in the dictionary, while `v` is the word that is the key in the dictionary.**  I've used the variable names `k` and `v` here only because you did too.  As noted in a comment, `text` and `word` might be better variable names in either the expanded `def f(...)` or the original `lambda` function.

#### Trace your code execution

Try the same code, except that instead of just:

```
def f(k, v):
    return k.replace(v, dictionary[v])
```

you write it as:

```
def f(text, word):
    print("f(text={!r}, word={!r})".format(text, word))
    replacement = dictionary[word]
    print("  I will now replace {!r} with {!r}".format(word, replacement))
    result = text.replace(word, replacement)
    print("  I got: {!r}".format(result))
    return result
```

Run the `functools.reduce` function over function `f` with `dictionary` and `string` as the other two arguments and observe the output.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I try to understand it but I dont get. Lets say, based on your example, the reduce function arguments for "func" should be "lambda k, v: k.replace(v, dictionary[v])" and "seq" should be "dictionary" then what about the "string" argument? why is it there?

Comment: The `string` in the call to `reduce` is the `initial` parameter. Note that `k` in your anonymous function is *not* a key, it's just a string: the first time through, it's the string `"there istest at the cardboards"`. Your variable `v` is also just a string, but you *use* it as a key when you use `dictionary[v]`.

Comment: You might make this more readable by changing the formal parameter names to, e.g., `def f(text, word)` and using `text.replace(word, dictionary[word])`. You can do the same in the lambda function.

Comment: I am sorry but I am getting even more confuse if you put it this way. So k represents the whole string "there istest at the cardboards" and v represent the whole string again or just a word in a string? Judging from the example, it supposed to represent a word but when you use string, then I will take it both k and v taking the string "there istest at the cardboards", am I right?

Comment: The latest comment is more understandable. Thank you so much.

Comment: I would like to ask, what is the point of just taking the string and keep applying the same function? from the example, def f(text, word) and using text.replace(word, dictionary[word]).... aint we doing "there istest at the cardboards".replace("there", dictionary["there"])>]

Comment: What is the point of keep replacing the same words inside a string. Please if can, show us some examples. Thank you

Comment: Could you change your example to tally with my example so that i can easily understand it. The current one I dont get why we iterate for i in dictionary and while you meantioned about k, v is string and word. These will be passed to the function and somehow the for i in dictionary means what?

Comment: @kingkongmanoftheworldinchaos: try writing `f` as a real function, as I showed. Then change it so that instead of immediately just returning its result, it first prints its arguments, then prints the result it will return, then return the result.

Comment: I tried to write the function and finally understand how it works now. Thank you so much sir!

Comment: The most generic and common names for the parameters of the function passed into `reduce` are called `accumulator` and `element` (not `k` and `v`): `element` gets every value of the iterable in order, just like in `map`; and `accumulator` accumulates the result of the operation as it's applied to successive elements. Think of how you would naturally add up all numbers from 1 to 10: you start with 0, then add 1 to that (accumulator: 1); then add 2 to that (accumulator: 3); then add 3 to that (accumulator: 6)... That's what reduce does: applies an operation and accumulates the result.

Comment: Thank you so much, now this answered my final doubt about the k and v. I will continue to learn. thank you so much.